# If $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{3}{2},$ find the value of $\frac{x^3+y^3}{2\sqrt{x^4-y^4}}.\frac{3y(x-y)}{x^3-x^2y+xy^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{3}{2},$ find the value of $$\dfrac{x^3+y^3}{2\sqrt{x^4-y^4}}.\dfrac{3y(x-y)}{x^3-x^2y+xy^2}.
$$
I think it's a good idea to simplify the expression at first: $$\dfrac{(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)}{2\sqrt{x^4-y^4}}.\dfrac{3(y-x)}{x(x^2-xy+y^2)}=\dfrac{x+y}{2\sqrt{x^4-y^4}}.\dfrac{3(y-x)}{x}.$$ I don't see how to further simplify. Thank you in advance! What can we do?

Comment: May be, replacing $y$ by $\frac {2x}3$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, We can't  simplify further?

Comment: The last factor is nothing is nothing else than $\frac{3y}{x} - 3$ e.g. And you can simplify the first factor by using binomial rules $(x-y)(x+y) = x^2-y^2$

Comment: After finishing simplification the term should be much much simpler and easy to solve

Comment: @LegNaiB, I don't understand how to simplify the first factor by using $(x-y)(x+y)=x^2-y^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{x^3+y^3}{2\sqrt{x^4-y^4}}.\dfrac{3y(x-y)}{x^3-x^2y+xy^2}$

$ = \dfrac{3}{2} \cdot \dfrac{(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)}{\sqrt{x^4-y^4}}.\dfrac{y \ (x-y)}{x (x^2-xy+y^2)}$

$ = \dfrac{3}{2} \cdot \dfrac{(x^2-y^2)}{\sqrt{x^4-y^4}}.\dfrac{y}{x}$

$ = \dfrac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{x^4-y^4}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{(x/y)^2-1}}{\sqrt{(x/y)^2+1}}$

$ = \dfrac{\sqrt{5/4}}{\sqrt{13/4}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{5}{13}}$

Comment: Thank you for the response! How is $$\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{x^4-y^4}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$??

Comment: Just like $\sqrt{a^2 - b^2} = \sqrt{(a-b)(a+b)}$, $ \sqrt{x^4-y^4} = \sqrt{(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)}$ and in numerator we have $(x^2-y^2)$ which is nothing but $(\sqrt{x^2-y^2})^2$.

Comment: I got it, thank you! But then how is $\sqrt{x^2-y^2}=\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^2-1}$? Sorry for the questions, but I want to understand the whole solution.

Comment: I divide both numerator and denominator of $\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ by $y$ so inside the square root it becomes division by $y^2$.

Comment: So clever! Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Note that we want to get rid of that pesky $\sqrt{x^4 - y^4}$. Where you left off is wrong as other people have said, as it should be:

$$\dfrac{x+y}{2\sqrt{x^4-y^4}} \dfrac{3y(x-y)}{x} = \dfrac{3y(x^2-y^2)}{2x\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)}} = \frac{3y}{2x \sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \frac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}} = \frac{3y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}{2x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$

and now $x = \frac{3}{2}y$ so we have:

$$\frac{3y\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}y^2-y^2}}{3y\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}y^2+y^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{9/4 - 1}}{\sqrt{9/4 + 1}} = \sqrt{\frac{5}{13}}.$$

Comment: Can you please clarify why $$\dfrac{-3y(x^2-y^2)}{2x\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)}} = \frac{-3y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}{2x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ Thank you!

Comment: Because $\frac{u}{\sqrt u} = \sqrt{u}$ with $u = x^2 - y^2$.

Comment: I didn't get that. Can you show me in the equation with $x$ and $y$? May I ask you to add one more equality in your answer to make things easier for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Medi take $\frac{2}{\sqrt 2}$ for example. Note that this is just equivalent to $\sqrt 2$ if you multiple both sides by $\sqrt 2.$ So here, instead of 2, you have $x^2-y^2$

Answer (score 0):

You lef out a y in your simplification and also a sign error.
$$\frac{3}{2} \frac{y(x+y)(x-y)}{x\sqrt{x^4 - y^4}} \cdot \frac{y^{-3}}{y^{-3}} = \frac{3}{2} \frac{\big(\frac{x}{y}\big)^2 -1}{\frac{x}{y}\sqrt{\big(\frac{x}{y}\big)^4 - 1}} = \sqrt{\frac{5}{13}} \approx 0.62 $$

Comment: That explains everything: I was missing a $y$ before but now, our answers agree with each other.

Answer (score 0):

1.take common of y^3 for first block of numerator and
2. take y common from second block of numerator

3.take y^4 common from first block of denominator ,take it out of square root to make it y^2
4.take y^3 common from second bracket of denominator

after these four steps every y power we took out will get cancel and
next substitute (x/y) powers correspondigly

sry for answering in text ,coz i dont know how to type powers in this editor ,hope i was helpful ,

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).